# Lost ownership of files after backing them up - how to regain full control

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions, windows-8.1

I backed-up important files from my old PC onto an external hard drive and whenever I try to delete, move, or open one of these files or folders, it tells me I do not have permission (access denied) to do that.

So I took ownership of those files, with elevated CMD, using:

`takeown /f filename`

The result was "SUCCESSFUL", however, this has not solved the problem. So I right-clicked a file `> Properties > Security > Edit > Add > Typed in my current Name > OK > Apply` - then tried to access the file again without success.

So I then tried `> Properties > Security > Advanced > Owner: Change > Enter my name > Apply` - then tried accessing the file again - no luck.

How can I regain full control of these files?

---

### Update:

*19:50PM AEST - 6/8/14*:

The result of `icacls bounce.wav` was:

```
E:\Audio>takeown /f "bounce.wav" /a & icacls "bounce.wav" /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544
:F /q

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "E:\Audio\bounce.wav" now owned by the administra
tors group.
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

E:\Audio>icacls "bounce.wav"
bounce.wav BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
           Home-PC\Jason:(I)(F)
           Everyone:(I)(F)
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Though, I am still unable to copy/move/open this file. The error given is:

> You require permission from Administrators to perform this action.

But I am an administrator.

Comment: Try running the following command: `takeown /f "file" /a & icacls "file" /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:F /q`

Comment: @and31415 thanks, I just ran that cmd and it said "SUCCESSFUL, file now owned by admin group" but I'm still unable to open/copy/move the file.

Comment: @and31415 I have updated my question to include the results from your last comment.

Comment: Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: @and31415 I figured out what the problem was; the problem was that these files (many and important ones) - I (at some point) decided to check the "Encrypt contents to secure data" option in Properties > Advanced - and that was done on the old computer (which I no longer have) and so on this new computer - they're still encrypted, but nothing is working cause they're encrypted. I even tried using RichCopy to decrypt them as suggested on TechNet site but it fails for most of the files saying "file not found" but it's _clearly_ there.

Comment: Unless you have a backup of the [Encryption File System (EFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) certificate/key, the files aren't likely to be recoverable.

Comment: @and31415 Would it be possible to boot into my other partition and use some tool on Ubuntu to somehow decrypt the contents?

Comment: The key to decrypt those files was stored on the old computer. Unless you have a whole disk image/backup from which you can recover it (or at least try to), these encrypted files are basically lost. Also, since the problem is not related to ownership/permissions you should reword the title, add more details to the question, and edit the tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is my "chown.bat" (unix folks will laugh at me using that name):

```
    for /r %fn in (*.*)  SetACL -on "%fn" -ot file -actn clear -clr dacl,sacl
    takeown /F * /R /D  Y
    icacls   *.* /T /C /grant %_winuser%:(D,WDAC)
    icacls    .  /T /C /grant administrators:F System:F everyone:F
```

SetACL is a 3rd party utility that needs to be in your path.